# Canon printer driver in Ubuntu for Canon image runner 2202n

Tags: printing

How to install appropriate driver for Canon image runner 2202n in Ubuntu?

In default printer drivers available in Ubuntu I have found Canon IR 2022 and 2200 but not Canon IR 2202n. Please provide the solution.

Comment: Can you print with the IR2200 driver? Canon printers are usually supported within a series.

Comment: No, I have tried IR2200. But not worked. Test page is not generated.

Comment: Finally I got it running. I have downloaded Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V290_uk_EN from this link http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100270808.html. Extracted and installed relavent debian packages(for may case 64-bit). After this action I have added network printer which worked fine for printing.

Comment: I am not able to use the scanner of this printer canon IR 2202n. Please let me know if you have fond the solution.

Comment: Did you install `scangearmp` of Canon?

Comment: Not able to figureout the exact verion which suits to the canon IR 2022n.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it running. I downloaded `Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V290_uk_EN` from http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100270808.html.

I extracted and installed the relevant `.deb` packages (for my case 64-bit). After this, I added network printer which worked fine for printing.