# Canon ir2420 installation

Tags: kubuntu, canon

Hello I am new to kubuntu. Can I please get a step by step installation for the driver of Canon Image Runner 2420. I tried to do it from printer settings but there is no driver available. If I could get a PPD file I hope that could solve the problem too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That printer is supported by the official Canon UFR II driver. Please try downloading the Canon UFR II Driver for Linux: http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0100003440/08/Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V290_us_EN.tar.gz Decompress that file and install the .deb that's most appropriate for your system (most computers these days are 64-bit), and then your printer should work. There is a tutorial here: http://www.mysolutions.it/tutorial-linux-driver-canon-ufr-ii-lt-printers/ and more information at https://wiki.debian.org/PrinterDriver/Canon/UFR-II

Comment: Another option if you just want .ppd files, there is a way to obtain them via a Canon Windows installer, using WINE:
http://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting#Canon

Comment: Possibly-related askubuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/537758/canon-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-for-canon-image-runner-2202n

Comment: I came across these links but were not helpful....

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not helpful"? Were you able to install the UFR II driver? Were you able to extract the PPDs using WINE and then import into Ubuntu? Did you run into problems, or did everything work perfectly and your printer's still not recognized?

Comment: Yes please....I extracted all the PPDs but the exact ppd for canon 2420 is not available and I keep getting "filter failed error" when I try to print, I assume this means it has not recognized my printer. Thanks

Comment: Hello All,  I installed the cndrvcups-ufr2-us_2.90-1_i386.deb file. and the missing element was a reboot. and now I have the driver installed for canon iR2420